# Localhost:3000 hot reload/live server is not working - React

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I'm having some trouble with React's hot reload, everytime I hit on CTRL + S, or save the project this one does not refresh on the browser and I need to refresh the page manually.
May be something on the config?
I'm still new on React and don't know about port configuration, i've only scripted in bash the create-react-app command and npm start.
I'll preciate the communities help.

Comment: Does any error or something show up at the terminal when modifying and saving the code?

Comment: That's the problem, the only thing I get in the console is the common: [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... but nothing else, there is no error in the console. Everytime I update a component the "live compiling" appears in the bash with every change but I cannot watch the changes on the browser. Do you know if is something related with the webpack files or maybe in the package.json?

Comment: maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148530/14689203) to a similar question can help.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it. Peace!